# convert a data varchar to date month

Tags: mysql, date, strtotime, str-to-date

I have a table with a date column in it, but its data type using a varchar.

> Month
>   | 01 02 03

I want to convert that data into a form of month name,I have tried this way, the data is successfully converted into months but always month of january.

```
foreach($list as $post) {
    $time = strtotime($post->album_periode_bulan);
    $newformat = date('F',$time);
    $no++;
    $row = array();
    $row[] = $no;
    $row[] = $time;
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

I have implemented this in datatables

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you do

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(your_column, '%m'), '%M');
```

and that's it. Read more about the format parameters for both functions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Note though, newer releases set the sql mode `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` by default. You might need to disable this temporarily with

```
set session sql_mode = "";
```

Check this before!!! with

```
show session variables like 'sql_mode';
```

or you might end with all your rows being `NULL`.